# Tish'a Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred nine?

### ?תשעה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 309.

Swim not in the waters of lazy gematria.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred eight entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: @WAF I seem to have been using the [British convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_differences#Numbers). Oops. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dafyomi.shemayisrael.co.il/parsha/vayera3.htm

Avraham Avinu called the Makom HaMikdash "Har".

Yitchok Avinu called it "Sadeh" - שדה = 309

Yaakov Avinu called it "Bayis"

> Avraham Avinu came and prayed on the
>   place where the Temple was to be,
>   opposite the heavenly Temple, and with
>   his prayers he added an additional
>   wall to the heavenly Temple -- a
>   second Machaneh of angels. Machaneh
>   (103) plus Machaneh (another 103)
>   equals 206. That is why Avraham called
>   it a "Har" [= mountain], the Gematria
>   of which is 205 (He = 5, Resh = 200.
>   One of the rules of Gematria is that
>   one may, at times, add 1 to the
>   combined numerical value of a word's
>   letters. This extra 1 corresponds to
>   the word as a whole. Adding an extra 1
>   in such a manner is referred to as "Im
>   Hakollel" [= with the total]. In such
>   a manner, the word "Har" equals
>   exactly 206, or 2x103.)
>
> Yitzchak prayed there and added
>   another Machaneh of angels to the
>   Heavenly Beit Hamikdash, giving it a
>   third "wall." Now that there were
>   three Machanot, he referred to it as a
>   **"Sadeh" [= field] which has the
>   Gematria of 309 (Sin = 300, Dalet = 4,
>   He = 5), or three times Machaneh
>   (103).**
>
> When Yakov prayed there he added a
>   fourth wall, making it a "Bayit" [=
>   house], which has the Gematria of four
>   times Machaneh (103), or 412 (Beit =
>   2, Yud = 10, Taf = 400).
>
> The Belzer Rebbe adds that the
>   heavenly Beit Hamikdash did not yet
>   have a ceiling -- just as the
>   tabernacle in the desert had four
>   walls but no ceiling, only a covering
>   of cloth. Later on, before Moshe
>   Rabbeinu was taken away from the Bnei
>   Yisrael, he was shown all of Eretz
>   Yisrael [= the Land of Israel],
>   including the place of the Beit
>   Hamikdash (Rashi, Devarim 3:25). At
>   that time Moshe Rabbeinu also prayed
>   for the completion of the heavenly
>   Beit Hamikdash. He prayed using the
>   word, "Va'etchanan [= and I pleaded]"
>   (Devarim 3:23). He used this word
>   because his prayer was to add a
>   ceiling -- a fifth Machaneh of angels
>   -- to the heavenly Beit Hamikdash. Five times Machaneh is 515, exactly
>   the Gematria of "Va'etchanan" (Vav =
>   6, Alef = 1, Taf = 400, Chet = 8, Nun
>   = 50, Nun = 50)!

Answer (score 1):

Off-topic but:

The number of Egyptian aircraft destroyed in the first morning of the Six-Day War is [disputed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Day_War#Preliminary_air_attack), but [some](http://books.google.com/books?id=9X5a1fgKqewC&pg=PA322) give it as 309 ([others](http://books.google.com/books?id=CkLHZCzMEJkC&pg=PA120&dq=309) give that number as destroyed by [some](https://www.google.com/search?q=309+june+egypt%7Cegyptian+israel%7Cisraeli) later point in the war).

Comment: Not off-topic if you consider these events to be part of a miraculous triumph that's the subject of [religious observance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Day#Religious_observance). If you do, then it's approximately equivalent to the number of Greek elephants killed by the Maccabim, as reported (if it is - I don't know) in the book named after them\, and almost equivalent to the number of Persian attackers killed by Jews, as reported in Esther (but not quite because the latter is recorded in the Scripture).